# Ansible 'raw' module - using escape characters in regex to perform 'sed' command

Tags: ansible

I want to use the raw module to run a 'sed' command which will contain escape characters.

```
- name: Search for prefix in file and replace all following text with addition
  raw: "sed 's/\({{ prefix }}\)\(.*\)/\1 {{ addition }}/g' {{ file }} > {{ file }}.test"
```

This, however complains with:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
found unknown escape character
```

With the '^' pointing at the first '\' in the string. How to I include escape characters in this command without ansible trying to process them?

Answer (score 1):

The task below works

```
- raw: 'sed --regexp-extended ''s/({{ prefix }})(.*)/\1 {{ addition }}/g'' {{ file }} > {{ file }}.test'
```

with variables

```
file: test
prefix: AAA
addition: XXX
```

gives

```
$ cat test
alsdjflaskdjfasn AAA fasdfasdfsadf

$ cat test.test 
alsdjflaskdjfasn AAA XXX
```

Modified regex from "^" till "$"

```
- raw: 'sed --regexp-extended ''s/^(.*)({{ prefix }})(.*)$/\1 {{ addition }}/g'' {{ file }} > {{ file }}.test2'
```

gives

```
$ cat test.test2
alsdjflaskdjfasn  XXX
```

Notes

- Use [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097)
- With [sed --regexp-extended](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) the parentheses don't have to be escaped.

Comment: Hi, this answer is great and worked, but could you explain the quotes, and why my quotes were incorrect?

Comment: Also in the second example, i think you're missing a '\2' after the '\1' to include the prefix